# Python Regular Expression / Middle word in result

Tags: python, regex

I have problem with unnecessary strings in result. I want pull only https from files. 
My code is:

```
import sys
import os
import hashlib
import re

if len(sys.argv) < 2 :
    sys.exit('Aby uzyc wpisz: python %s filename' % sys.argv[0])

if not os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
    sys.exit('BLAD!: Plik "%s" nie znaleziony!' % sys.argv[1])

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f:
    plik = f.read()
    print("MD5: %s" % hashlib.md5(plik).hexdigest())
    print("SHA1: %s" % hashlib.sha1(plik).hexdigest())
    print("SHA256: %s" % hashlib.sha256(plik).hexdigest())
    print("Podejrzane linki: \n")
    pliki = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
    for line in pliki:
        if re.search("(H|h)ttps:(.*)",line):
            print(line)
        elif re.search("(H|h)ttp:(.*)",line):
            print(line)
    pliki.close()
```

In result:

```
MD5: f16a93fd2d6f2a9f90af9f61a19d28bd
SHA1: 0a9b89624696757e188412da268afb2bf5b600aa
SHA256: 3b365deb0e272146f00f9d723a9fd4dbeacddc10123aec8237a37c10c19fe6df
Podejrzane linki: 

        GrizliPolSurls = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" 

        FilnMoviehttpsd.Open "GET", "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",False
```

I want only strings in `""` and starts from `http` or `https` e.g `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Desired result:

```
MD5: f16a93fd2d6f2a9f90af9f61a19d28bd
SHA1: 0a9b89624696757e188412da268afb2bf5b600aa
SHA256: 3b365deb0e272146f00f9d723a9fd4dbeacddc10123aec8237a37c10c19fe6df
Podejrzane linki: 
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: What do you mean by :- I want only strings in "" and starts from http or https e.g http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. Do you want to strip "http://" and "https://"

Comment: Just get result like this :MD5: f16a93fd2d6f2a9f90af9f61a19d28bd
SHA1: 0a9b89624696757e188412da268afb2bf5b600aa
SHA256: 3b365deb0e272146f00f9d723a9fd4dbeacddc10123aec8237a37c10c19fe6df
Podejrzane linki: 
"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
"https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

Comment: Can you give an example for the input data? (sys.argv[1])

Comment: I will edit general question and add my desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re.search() returns a [Match Object](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#match-objects)

You have to fetch the information from the result:

```
line = "my text line contains a http://192.168.1.1 magic url"
result = re.search("[Hh]ttps?://\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+", line)
print(result.group())  # will print http://192.168.1.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.findall` with the following regex (explained on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/heGjWk/1)):

```
"([Hh]ttps?.*?)"
```

so:

```
import re
s = '''MD5MD5:: f16a93fd2d6f2a9f90af9f61a19d28bd
SHA1 f16a93fd2 : 0a9b89624696757e188412da268afb2bf5b600aa
SHA256: 3b365deb0e272146f00f9d723a9fd4dbeacddc10123aec8237a37c10c19fe6df
Podejrzane linki: 

        GrizliPolSurls = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" 

        FilnMoviehttpsd.Open "GET", "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",False'''
urls = re.findall('"([Hh]ttps?.*?)"', s)
#['http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx']
```

Comment: Please read desire result. I guess I had to explain it not clearly

Answer (score 1):

You need this pattern: `(?<=")http[^"]+`.

`(?<=")` - positive lookbehind, to determine if `"` precceds current position.

`http` - match `http` literally.

`[^"]+` - match everything until `"`, this is negated class technique to avoid quantifiers :)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V71hIv/1)